# DSC V5 - Keeps attempting to reapply a failed configuraiton

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-5.0

We have started using DSC to deploy some applications.  We are pushing out the configurations and only want it to run this configuration once and then stop.  However it seems that if a configuration fails we end up with a pending configuration which DSC seems to keep attempting to reapply.  Is this intended behavior?  Is there anyway for us to prevent this happening.

Here are our LCM settings

```
ActionAfterReboot              : ContinueConfiguration
AgentId                        : 4314CBF5-928E-11E5-941E-00155D0****
AllowModuleOverWrite           : True
CertificateID                  : EBB297F164BDA1C1A7918C12C31D0F70110****
ConfigurationDownloadManagers  : {[ConfigurationRepositoryWeb]DSCHTTP}
ConfigurationID                : 3fa96bab-ac50-4b80-a9ac-384bfd*****
ConfigurationMode              : ApplyOnly
ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins : 15
Credential                     : 
DebugMode                      : {NONE}
DownloadManagerCustomData      : 
DownloadManagerName            : 
LCMCompatibleVersions          : {1.0, 2.0}
LCMState                       : Idle
LCMStateDetail                 : 
LCMVersion                     : 2.0
StatusRetentionTimeInDays      : 10
PartialConfigurations          : 
RebootNodeIfNeeded             : True
RefreshFrequencyMins           : 30
RefreshMode                    : Push
ReportManagers                 : {}
ResourceModuleManagers         : {[ResourceRepositoryWeb]DSCHTTP}
PSComputerName                 : D6B*****01
PSComputerName                 : D6B*****01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a blog that explains how LCM behaves and how you can get out of it http://nanalakshmanan.github.io/blog/Converging-to-a-desired-state/

Comment: Yeah, it does make sense, but unfortunately we are not using dsc quite as intended.  But using it as a base desired state (syncing dev environments back to Main) then deploying changed services over the top.  We are working towards dynamically generating the mof files to be the real desired state but until then we are checking the dsc run for errors and if so removing the pending.mof.